# PHP function to recognize the lowest of the 3 numbers and change its class?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Below I echo 3 numbers. One of these number is the lowest of 3. What is a function that I can use so as to recognize the lowest of the 3 and in that case change the class `text-success` to `text-warning` ?

I have a lot of blocks of 3 numbers, so the below is just one of them, so I believe a more "universal" approach may be ideal.

```
<p class="all-caps font-montserrat  no-margin text-success "><?=mysql_result($stats, 0,4);?></p>

<p class="all-caps font-montserrat  no-margin text-success "><?=mysql_result($stats, 1,4);?></p>

<p class="all-caps font-montserrat  no-margin text-success "><?=mysql_result($stats, 2,4);?></p>
```

Comment: use php's `min()` function http://php.net/min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS specification does not support selection based on content, you can match on an element, the name of an attribute in the element, and the value of a named attribute in an element. When matching a named attribute value, you are doing a string regular like expression match, so you cannot find the lowest value either.

Now if you order the numbers, you can use CSS :first-child or :last modifier to select the first or last element.

If you are not ordering, you get 2 options: add the class from PHP or javascript.

PHP:
Note for PHP you should be using mysqli vs mysql, since mysql is deprecated.

```
$arr =array () ;
while ( ($record =mysql_result ($stats, 1, 4)) )
    $arr [] =$record ;
$min =array_reduce ($arr, function ($carry, $item) {
    return (min ($carry, $item)) ;
}, PHP_INT_MAX) ;
foreach ( $arr as $key => $item ) {
    ?><p class="all-caps font-montserrat no-margin <?= $item <= $min ? 'text-warning' : 'text-success' ?>"><?= $item ?></p><?
}
```

javascript using JQuery

```
var elt, min =Number.MAX_VALUE, arr =$('p.text-success') ;
for ( var i =0 ; i < arr.length ; i++ ) {
    if ( arr [i] <= min ) {
        min =parseInt (arr [i].text ()) ;
        elt =arr [i] ;
}
elt.addClass ('text-warning').removeClass ('text-success') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

push three numbers in to an `array`

for example `array(23, 9, 11);`

then

```
<?php 
 $min = min($numbers);
 foreach ($numbers as $number) {
     $class = ($number == $min) ? 'warning' : 'success';
     echo "<p class='all-caps font-montserrat  no-margin text-$class'>$number</p>";
 }
?>
```

hope it helps

Comment: you should learn the "don't repeat yourself" (DRY) principle - see http://pastebin.com/nNVSqfX1

Comment: Thanks for directing me in good programmers way,I will learn @Alnitak  :) Updated the answer

Comment: @Alnitak how can I have this in function so as not to copy paste it in all of my blocks?

Comment: @villoui that's probably a separate question, and also depends on what else varies (if anything) in the repeated blocks.  Note that my code doesn't show the copying of the results from MySQL _into_ the `$numbers` array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.This code may help you to place blocks as per database result.

**NB:** *Try to use mysqli or PDO statements because mysql extension is deprecated*

```
<?php
        $result = mysql_query("YOUR QUERY HERE");
            //echo mysql_result($result, 4,9);
            $values = array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
             $values[] = $row[4]; 

            $min = min($values);    
            foreach($values as $val)
            {
              $addstr = ($val == $min) ? "text-warning":"text-success";
              echo '<p class="all-caps font-montserrat  no-margin '.$addstr.'">'.$val.'</p>';
            }
?>
```